# QSqlDatabase: How to avoid 'qt_sql_default_connection' still in use & duplicate connection related warning?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

Sorry if this is a trivial question but I have been trying to build a small .ui that used `QSQLITE` as database and that uses `QTableView` to show 4 columns on a default database file as example.

I debugged the problem in every side, changed logical operations of the `SQL` and restructured the constructor in a more simple way but the error still stays.

After finishing to set up all parameters I am getting this error:

`QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.`

And

`QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.`

I looked on several sources that describe this error such as [this source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase), this [other source](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/47303-Qt-Check-if-there-is-an-open-database-connection). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827940/qsqldatabaseprivateremovedatabase-connection-myconnectionname-is-still-in-u) was useful but still nothing happens. Official documentation suggests a "wrong" and "right" way to do that [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase). but the error still stays. After all these different options I brought back the code to a more concise way and I hope that someone can shed light on this issue.

Below the snipped of code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    QString temporaryFolder;
    dataInfo *mNewDatabaseImages;
    QSqlTableModel *mNewTableImages;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    temporaryFolder = "/home/to/Desktop/tempDBFolder/tmp.db";
    QFile dbRem(temporaryFolder);
    dbRem.remove();
    mNewDatabaseImages = new dataInfo(this);
    mNewDatabaseImages->initDataBase(temporaryFolder);
    mNewDatabaseImages->confDataBase();
    mNewTableImages = new QSqlTableModel(this, mNewDatabaseImages->getDatabase());
    mNewTableImages->setTable("leftCamTable");
    mNewTableImages->select();
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(mNewTableImages);
    ui->bookMarkTableView->showColumn(true);
}
```

**datainfo.h**

```
#ifndef DATAINFO_H
#define DATAINFO_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include "imageparam.h"

class dataInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dataInfo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool initDataBase(const QString &nameDB);
    bool confDataBase();
    bool addItem(ImageParam* imageItem);
    QSqlDatabase getDatabase();
private:
    QString mError;
    QSqlDatabase mDBImages;
};
#endif // DATAINFO_H
```

**datainfo.cpp**

```
#include "datainfo.h"
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMessageBox>

#define CREATE_TABLE \
    " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imageTable" \
    " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
    " path1 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " path2 TEXT NOT NULL" \
    " imageA BLOB NOT NULL" \
    " imageB BLOB NOT NULL)"

dataInfo::dataInfo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

bool dataInfo::initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)
{
    mDBImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mDBImages.setDatabaseName(nameDB);
    bool ok = mDBImages.open();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = mDBImages.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << mError;
    }
    return ok;
}

bool dataInfo::confDataBase()
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    bool ok = qry.exec(CREATE_TABLE);
    if(!ok) {
        mError = qry.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}

bool dataInfo::addItem(ImageParam *imageItem)
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO imageTable (path1, path2, imageA, imageB)" \
                " VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    qry.addBindValue(imageItem->path1());
    qry.addBindValue(imageItem->path2());
    qry.addBindValue(imageItem->image1());
    qry.addBindValue(imageItem->image2());
    bool ok = qry.exec();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = qry.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}

QSqlDatabase dataInfo::getDatabase()
{
    return mDBImages;
}
```

I looked also at [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/15962/solved-qsqldatabaseprivate-removedatabase-connection-is-still-in-use-all-queries-will-cease-to-work/3) that suggested to set a name to the databse first but I already do that in the function `initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)`. Here the [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/15962/solved-qsqldatabaseprivate-removedatabase-connection-is-still-in-use-all-queries-will-cease-to-work/3) that suggested the procedure, which is below:

```
db->setDatabaseName("name");
if(!db->open()) {
    qDebug() << "Error opening ";
    return false;
}
```

Please shed light on the possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

- You should specify the database you want to run your [`QSqlQuery`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) on, otherwise they will run on the default database. You can specify the database in `QSqlQuery`'s constructor with

  `QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("my-db"));`
- You are keeping a copy of the `QSqlDatabase` as a member of your `dataInfo` class, which will prevent it prevent closing properly. Instead, just use the static `QSqlDatabase::database("name")` when needed.

  `auto db = QSqlDatabase::database("my-db");`

### Details

**Providing the right database to QSqlQuery**

Change all your uses of `QSqlQuery`. For example for `confDataBase`:

```
bool dataInfo::confDataBase()
{
    // Explicitly provide your database to the query
    // Otherwise the default database is used
    QSqlQuery qry(getDatabase());
    bool ok = qry.exec(CREATE_TABLE);
    if(!ok) {
        mError = qry.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

**Not keeping QSqlDatabase attributes**

From the documentation:

> **Warning**: It is highly recommended that you do not keep a copy of the QSqlDatabase around as a member of a class, as this will prevent the instance from being correctly cleaned up on shutdown. If you need to access an existing QSqlDatabase, it should be accessed with database(). If you chose to have a QSqlDatabase member variable, this needs to be deleted before the QCoreApplication instance is deleted, otherwise it may lead to undefined behavior.

Store your database's name in your class instead, and change your `getDatabase` to

*dataInfo.cpp*

```
bool dataInfo::initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)
{
    // Save database's name
    mDBName = nameDB;
    // Use the database locally, without storing it
    auto dbImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", nameDB);
    bool ok = dbImages.open();
    if(!ok) {
        mError = dbImages.lastError().text();
        qDebug() << mError;
    }
    return ok;
}

QSqlDatabase dataInfo::getDatabase()
{
    return QSqlDatabase::database(mDBName);
}
```

*dataInfo.h*

```
private:
    QString mError;
    QString mDBName;
```

**Qt's code generating the warning**

To have a look at the actual code producing the error: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/kernel/qsqldatabase.cpp.html#170

`invalidateDb` is used when connections are added or removed, and will trigger the error if the reference count > 1. As you are holding onto one, this will trigger the error.

Comment: @ Adrien Leravat, thanks for taking the time to read the question. I changed the `getDatabase()` function as you suggested but it is still not working yet. I think also you are referring on modifying the `initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)` function that carries this statement `mDBImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` But how should that function be  modified?

Comment: Ok. I don't think changing `mDBImages = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` would help, you are fine just using a local instance. Can you give a shot at passing the database name directly in `addDatabase(...)` call, as the 2nd argument? Do you have any other QSqlDatabase elsewhere? I remember having the issue and I had to manually close every database, and ensure no queries were active, but the `default` name in your warning is really odd to me.

Comment: Also, does the problem go away if you don't provide the database to `QSqlTableModel`? And if you commend your `QSqlTableModel` code altogether? Did you get rid of `QSqlDatabase mDBImages;` in the header as well? So many questions :)

Comment: No problem :) I appreciate your time in helping! I am trying your suggestions right now. Give me a couple of minutes to verify.

Comment: Small progress: if I get rid of `QSqlDatabase mDBImages;` from the .h file and I turn the `initDataBase(const QString &nameDB)` function with only this statement `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");` now the compiler says `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open`

Comment: Ok, yeah you still need to have your DB open. I just edited my answer to make it clearer, with all changes you need! (hopefully)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190171/discussion-between-adrien-leravat-and-emanuele).

Comment: Thanks so much for your time Adrien Leravat!