# How to programmatically pass QLineEdit content into QTableView rows using QPushButton

Tags: c++11, qt5, qtableview, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I am trying to programmatically pass the content of a `QLineEdit` into rows of a `QTableView` using a `QPushButton`. I was wondering if there is anyone who can provide some guidance on how to do that.

Basically this is the initial situation:

[image: initial_layout]

and this is what I am trying to achieve using the `QPushButton` "Send To TableView" in a dynamical way, which mean that every time I change image and its related content shown inside the two `QLineEdit` I hit "Send To TableView" and the content is saved as shown below:

[image: goal]

Every time I change image I repeat the process.

`QSQLITE` is the databse that is handling all the `SQL` for the `QTableView`. It is structured [using this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199965/qsqldatabase-how-to-avoid-qt-sql-default-connection-still-in-use-duplicate) from my previous question.

How to easily achieve that? 
Thanks for shedding light on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about this post that a very quick and easy answer is the following:

**mainwindow.h**

```
private slots:
    void on_sendBtn_clicked();
    void addData();
```

On the constructor put:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    model = new QStandardItemModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Create the function that will be passed to the `QPushButton`

```
void MainWindow::on_sendBtn_clicked()
{
    addData();
}

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    QStandardItem *pathAItem = new QStandardItem(ui->pathLineEdit_A->text());
    QStandardItem *pathBItem = new QStandardItem(ui->pathLineEdit_B->text());

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << pathAItem << pathBItem;
    model->appendRow(row);
}
```

Hope this will be helpful should anyone needs