# QSqlTableModel and QSQLITE not showing correct columns & header

Tags: sql, c++11, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

On a user interface I have a `QTableView` that looks like this at the very beginning after first start:

[image: QTableView]

As soon as the user run the project and create a new database `.db` (say the user puts the .db file on the Desktop), this `QTableView` looks like this which the **correct behavior**:

[image: Correct_QTableView]

**The problem:** After I start saving images and their path all the headers carries different names (1,2,3,4) instead of (path1, path2, image1, image2) as shown previously and there is an `id` column missing, like this below which is the **wrong behavior**:

[image: wrong]

Below is how I am setting the most important parameters:

**mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    QString temporaryFolder;
    dataInfo *mNewDatabaseImages;
    QSqlTableModel *mNewTableImages;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    temporaryFolder = "/home/path/toDesktop/folder/a.db";
    QFile dbRem(temporaryFolder);
    dbRem.remove();

    mNewDatabaseImages = new dataInfo(this);
    mNewDatabaseImages->initDataBase(temporaryFolder);
    mNewDatabaseImages->confDataBase();
    mNewTableImages = new QSqlTableModel(this, mNewDatabaseImages->getDatabase());
    mNewTableImages->setTable("imageTable");
    mNewTableImages->select();
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(mNewTableImages);

    model = new QStandardItemModel();
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(model);
    ui->bookMarkTableView->showColumn(true);
}
```

In addition to that there are two icons on the user interface with which I open an existing database or I create a new database as it is possible to see below:

[image: icons]

This part is on the **mainwindow.cpp** too and below is the snipped of code:

```
void MainWindow::openDatabase(MainWindow::Opening opening)
{
    QString nameDatabase;
    if(opening == OPENING) {
        nameDatabase = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    "Open Database", QDir::rootPath(),
                                                    "Database (*.db);;Any type (*.*)");
    } else {
        nameDatabase = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                    "New Database", QDir::rootPath(),
                                                    "Database (*.db);;Any type (*.*)");
    }
    if(nameDatabase.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if(!mNewDatabaseImages->initDataBase(nameDatabase)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", mNewDatabaseImages->getError());
        return;
    }
    if(!mNewDatabaseImages->confDataBase()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", mNewDatabaseImages->getError());
        return;
    }
    delete mNewTableImages;
    // Work with the database file created
    mNewTableImages = new QSqlTableModel(this, mNewDatabaseImages->getDatabase());
    mNewTableImages->setTable("imageTable");
    mNewTableImages->select();
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(mNewTableImages);
    ui->bookMarkTableView->showColumn(true);
}
```

The database I am using is `QSQLITE` and the way the `SQL` is written is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199965/qsqldatabase-how-to-avoid-qt-sql-default-connection-still-in-use-duplicate) if there is any need to see the snipped of that too.

Why does `QTableView` is not showing the correct headers and columns?

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting it with a new `QStandardItemModel`, therefore every time the program runs all the headers disappears. Try to modify your constructor by commenting out the last three lines in the following way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    temporaryFolder = "/home/path/toDesktop/folder/a.db";
    QFile dbRem(temporaryFolder);
    dbRem.remove();

    mNewDatabaseImages = new dataInfo(this);
    mNewDatabaseImages->initDataBase(temporaryFolder);
    mNewDatabaseImages->confDataBase();
    mNewTableImages = new QSqlTableModel(this, mNewDatabaseImages->getDatabase());
    mNewTableImages->setTable("imageTable");
    mNewTableImages->select();
    ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(mNewTableImages);


    // In this way you don't overwrite your initial headers

    //  model = new QStandardItemModel();
    //  ui->bookMarkTableView->setModel(model);
    //  ui->bookMarkTableView->showColumn(true);
}
```